# How to regenerate indium wires for vacuum seals?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals

I have a setup consisting in a vessel that eventually gets at low temperatures (approximately 85K - 87K) and needs indium wire as sealant. Unfortunately, we have to frequently open and close this setup to replace the internal components under test or measurement and I was wondering whether I could recycle the used indium.
In particular, I know that a former colleague was melting it inside a vial on a flame, together with citric acid powder pre-melted in the same vial. After this melting he was remaking the wire by simple extrusion.

Now the main questions are the following: has onyone ever heard about this "in house" process? Does anyone know the role of the acid? Is it used just to avoid oxydation during the melting stage?

Also, has anyone some reference (scientific articles or reviews) on the techniques for the regeneration of used indium gaskets/o-rings (not from electronic scrapes)?

Thank you so much for any answer.

Comment: I knew people who just hand rolled them back to being fat enough to compress again. The Indium corporation used to recycle your old wire and give a credit for new wire. Not sure about these days. All depends how cheap you want to go.

Comment: Thank you Jon for your answer. Actually, we open the vessel up to 3 times a week for replacing the internal setup. At the moment we seal il with an ISO flange with viton gasket. It is great untill we do not cool down the internal argon to liquify it. At that point is very difficult to avoid that the external air leaks in the chamber and spoil the purity argon (below the ppm). So, I thought that it would be great to modify the sealing with indium instead of redesigning from scratch the entire setup.